# How do you move a tile in OpenTTD

Tags: openttd

Can you move a tile in OpenTTD 1.5.2 (depot, station, etc)? If so, how do you do it? I don't want to demolish it.

Comment: Can you specify clearly what you mean by move? In general everything you do in the game, including construction and purchasing of vehicles is permanent. The game explicitly does not allow you to undo anything, so barring destroying and rebuilding I'm fairly sure moving something isn't allowed.

Comment: I don't see what the down vote is for. The question is as clear as daylight. Anyway, you answered it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot 'move' any structure you have constructed. The game does not allow you to undo any action, be it construction or purchases.

To move something, you have to build the structure somewhere else, then remove the original. For stations, as long as the new station is within a certain radius of the original and you construct the replacement first, the new station will be grouped together with the original. This may also work for other structures, but further testing is needed.

Comment: With stations, so long as the new station is on a directly adjacent tile (not diagonally adjacent) it will be linked to the existing one. It's not determined by radius.

Comment: @KingJ Nope - https://wiki.openttd.org/Distant-join_stations

Comment: That only applies if you hold control when placing though, if you're just placing normally it won't join unless it is directly adjacent. I read your answer as saying that you could place normally within a given radius, rather than needing to hold control.